# How to stop the @JsonProperty causing the parent class serializer to be used?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, annotations, jackson-databind

I am upgrading jackson-databind from version 2.9.0 to 2.9.8 and am running into an issue where the `@JsonProperty` value is causing spring to map the `@JsonSerialize` value from the parent method with the same name.

Example of the sub class:

```
public class SubClassEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @JsonView(SubClassEntity.class)
    @JsonProperty("user")
    @JsonSerialize(using = UserSubClassEntitySerialzer.class)
    public Entity getSubClassUser() {
        return super.getEntity();
    }

    @JsonView(SubClassEntity.class)
    @JsonProperty("userAlternative")
    public UserEntity getSubClassUserAlternative() {
        final User user = super.getUserAlternative();
        return null != user ? new UserEntity(user) : null;
    }
}
```

Example of the parent class

```
public class AbstractEntity {

        protected final Entity entity;

    public AbstractEntity (final Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public Entity getEntity() {
        return this.entity;
    }

    @JsonView(Object.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = UserInfoSerializer.class)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.entity.getUser();
    }

    @JsonView(Object.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = UserInfoSerializer.class)
    public User getUserAlternative() {
        return this.entity.getUserAlternative();
    }
}
```

The UserSubClassEntitySerialzer

```
public class UserSubClassEntitySerialzer extends JsonSerializer<Entity> {

does stuff

}
```

The UserInfoSerializer

```
public class UserInfoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User> {

does stuff

}
```

When we attempt to serialize the subclass the JsonSerializer set on the parent class of the name found in the JsonProperty is being used regardless of if one is set in the subclass. This cause a ClassCastException:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: package.UserEntity cannot be cast to package.User(through reference chain: package.SubClassEntity["userAlternative"])
```

and

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: package.Entity cannot be cast to package.User(through reference chain: package.SubClassEntity["user"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:993)
```

Is there a way for the subclass to ignore the JsonProperty value when it comes to determining the serializer?

Comment: Use "@JsonTypeInfo" and "@JsonSubTypes" which maintain subtype information while serializing java object and recreate the exact subtype.